# How to send message if there is no argument passed in python

Tags: python

so I tried to make a discord bot, and whenever I type the .clear command it will delete the message but I have to type the number of messages I want to delete in the command e.g .clear 5. However, I want to send a message whenever someone types the command without defining the number, and I use try exceptions but it still doesn't work as I expected

here's the code

```
@client.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount):
    try:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(amount))
    except MissingRequiredArgument:
        await ctx.send(f"give the number of message you want to delete - e.g '.clear 5' ")
```

error messages

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yves/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/yves/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "/home/yves/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "/home/yves/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "/home/yves/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: amount is a required argument that is missing.
```

Comment: How does this stack trace relate to the code shown?

Comment: try ```except discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument:``` if this does not work just leave it as ```except:```

Comment: @jarmod so basically, the function name stands for whatever the command is that's why the function name is clear as the command is also .clear. And ctx means the bot that is going to execute some sort of command as it shown in the code 'ctx.send' means the bot will send a message. And lastly, amount means the number of messages we want to delete

Comment: @baisbdhfug i've tried these two but still not working properly and saying the same error messages

Comment: As you can see, the `MissingRequiredArgument` exception occurs _while_ trying to call the `clear` function, so _before_ that function starts executing.  Thus, it's not possible to catch it _within_ the function since the function is never executed because of that error.

Comment: @ForceBru thanks for the explanation now i got the logic, but do you have any advice or solutions that I might use to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a command extension that accepts a [variable](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#variable) number of arguments. You can then test `len(args)` in your code.

For example:

```
@client.command()
async def clear(ctx, *args):
    if len(args) != 1:
        await ctx.send(f"give the number of message you want to delete - e.g '.clear 5' ")
    else:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(args[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Python supports default arguments:

```
@client.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount=None):
    if amount is None:
        await ctx.send(f"give the number of message you want to delete - e.g '.clear 5' ")
    else:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(amount))
```

Basically, if `amount is None`, you know that the user didn't supply the `amount` argument in their command.